# Odd Behavior when appending JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, json, post

So I have a JSON file containing basketball player information in the following format:

```
[{"name":"Lamar Patterson","team":1,"yearsLeft":0,"position":"PG","PPG":17},{"name":"Talib Zanna", "team":1,"yearsLeft":0,"position":"SF","PPG":13.1},....]
```

I want a user to be a able to add their own custom players to this file. To do this i try the following:

```
<?php 
        $json = file_get_contents('json/players.json');
        $info = json_decode($json, true);
        $info[] = array('name'=>$name, 'team'=>$team, 'yearsLeft'=>4, 'position'=>$position, 'PPG'=>$ppg);
        file_put_contents('json/players.json', json_encode($info));
    ?>
```

This "sort of" works. But when I check the JSON file, I find that there are 3 new entries rather than 1:

```
{"name":"","team":null,"yearsLeft":4,"position":"","PPG":""},{"name":"","team":"3","yearsLeft":4,"position":"","PPG":""},{"name":"Jeff","team":null,"yearsLeft":4,"position":"C","PPG":"23"}
```

assuming $name="Jeff" $team=3 and $ppg=23 (populated via POST submission).

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the source file is correct? No lose comma's, etc.?

Comment: Are you doing POST using ajax? Some double-binded clicks may trigger extra entries. Just to be sure

Comment: And you're sure no race condition is going on, like multiple people adding records simultaneously? I can't reproduce your issue. Where do you set `$name`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
//get the posted values
$name = $_POST['name'];
$team = $_POST['team'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$ppg = $_POST['ppg'];

//verify they're not empty
if(!empty($name) && !empty($team) && !empty($position) && !empty($ppg)) {
        //Open the file
        $fh = fopen('json/players.json', 'r+') or die("can't open file");

        //get file info/stats
        $stat = fstat($fh);

        //final desired size after trimming the trailing ']'
        $size = $stat['size']-1;

        //file has contents? then remove the trailing ']'
        if($size>0) ftruncate($fh, $size);

        //close the current handle
        fclose($fh);

        // reopen the file for append
        $fh = fopen('json/players.json', 'a');

        //build your data array
        $info = array('name'=>$name, 'team'=>$team, 'yearsLeft'=>4, 'position'=>$position, 'PPG'=>$ppg);
         //if this is not the first item on file
        if($size>0) fwrite($fh, ','.json_encode($info).']'); //append with comma
        else fwrite($fh, '['.json_encode($info).']'); //first item on file
        fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

Maybe your php config is not set to convert the post/get variables to global variables. This happened to me a couple of times so I rather create the variables I'm expecting from the post/get request. Also watch out for the page encoding, from personal experience you could be getting empty strings there.

Comment: Please use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Done. You are right, I dig for $_REQUEST in case I'm trying to get things either on the GET or POST and don't really care where they were being posted. But it might lead to other issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the following:

**Untested code**

```
<?php
if(!empty($name) && !empty($team) && !empty($position) && !empty($ppg)) {
    $fh = fopen('json/players.json', 'r+') or die("can't open file");
    $stat = fstat($fh);
    ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-1);//removes last ] char
    fclose($fh); 
    $fh = fopen('json/players.json', 'a');
    $info = array('name'=>$name, 'team'=>$team, 'yearsLeft'=>4, 'position'=>$position, 'PPG'=>$ppg);
    fwrite($fh, ','.json_encode($info).']');
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

This will append the only the new json to the file instead of opening the file, making php parse all the json and then writing it to the file again. In addition to that it will only store the data if the variables actually contain data.

Comment: This code first of all is more efficient and it might solve the problem in the case that php's json_decode isn't interpreting your json data correctly.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this results in the same problem. Could the problem lie somewhere in the fact that these variables are defined at different places in my code?

Comment: It seems like that then multiple post requests are being made to this script. Perhaps try adding a check to see if $name, $team, $position and $ppg are not null before storing the data.

Comment: ^ That was it. Thanks for the tip about checking if null! I should mention that this code, however, adds json arrays AFTER the ending ] in the file. It also does not add commas in between the } and {

Comment: Yes that's right, then you might indeed want to do use your old code just only with the check to see if it is null or not. That code however will become slow as the json file grows bigger. Alternatively you could make the script delete the ] from the file and then readd it.

Comment: I updated the answer with code which should work I think, however it won't make much of a difference unless your file is very big.

Comment: And you're sure that the last character is a `]`, not a `}`? IMHO, this is a very cumbersome solution to a minor bottleneck. And this doesn't answer the question *why* multiple post requests are made.